# How do I change EC2 user from ubuntu to mongodb?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

Launched Ubuntu 14.04 LTS micro instance on EC2, installed latest MongoDB following [their official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). When I run `sudo mongod --fork --dbpath /somedbpath --logpath /somelogpath` followed by `mongo`,

I get the warning that it shouldn't be run as a root user. I did notice the installation process created a mongodb user and group and I can see them in the outputs of `compgen -u` and `compgen -g` respectively. I shutdown the mongod server and even deleted all files created in the dbpath directory. Now, I'd like to run the daemon as mongodb user, as I've learned it has all the appropriate permissions and ulimits required for optimal performance.

How do I switch from ubuntu to mongodb user, though? I ran `sudo passwd mongodb` and updated a password. Then I tried `su mongodb`, entered the password when prompted, but hitting ENTER kept me logged in as ubuntu only. I tried logging out and back in. I manually created the mongodb dir under /home since it wasn't present. I even created a .ssh dir inside that and copied the authorized_keys file from /home/ubuntu/.ssh to see if I can log into the server by `ssh -i pemfile mongodb@serveruri` but it throws `Permission denied (publickey).` I'm inclined to following the best practices and would like to be able to launch the mongo daemon as mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I had to change permissions on the data directory (and it's files) and the log path, like so -

```
cd /var/log
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb mongodb/

cd /
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb data/
```

Then I ran the command similar to [7171u](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451006/7171u)'s answer, i.e,

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --fork --dbpath /data/ --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

And the warning's gone!

Answer (score 0):

Run commands as mangodb user do:

```
sudo -u mangodb mongod --fork --dbpath /somedbpath --logpath /somelogpath
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I answered my own question to describe the steps I had to run.

Answer (score 0):

Its good that you solved it on your own, but this is still not clear to you.

go through the below mentioned link, to understand the role of each user.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

mongod user is the one which doesnot have a home directory, that's why not /home, and it also does not have a shell too. check your /etc/passwd file for the mongod user.

```
mongod:x:993:990:mongod:/var/lib/mongo:/bin/false
```

this is the default entry for the mongod user in the above mentioned file.

its home directory is /var/lib/mongo
and its shell is false.